# Get info about caller and parameters (name and value) of a Func<T> delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a class that expose a public method (ExecuteJob) that accept a Func delegate and run it asyncronusly. I need to know info about:

1. The Caller (class and method name that invoke ExecuteJob)
2. List of parameter and it's value used to call Func delegate
3. If it's possible, before run Func delegate, set value of specific parameter of this delegate

Example Code

```
    public static class JobHandlerManager
          {
            public static async Task ExecuteJob<T>(Func<T> MetodoDaEseguire)
            {
              Params parOfMethod = MetodoDaEseguire.GetMethodParams();                  
              // here I need to get info about above points
              string Caller = "ExternalMethod"
              string Parameters = "\"par1\" = \"a\", \"par2\" = 10, \"par3\" = [\"x\", \"y\", \"z\"] "
              int JobID = CalculateJobId();
              parOfMethod = parOfMetho.add(JobID);
              Func<T> NewMethod = MetodoDaEseguire(parOfMethod);
              Task.Run(MetodoDaEseguire);
            }
          }

     

 public void DoStuff(string par1, int par 2, string[] arraypar, int JobID)
      {
        // JobID is set by JobHandlerManager.ExecuteJob
      }
      public void ExternalMethod()
      {
        JobHandlerManager.ExecuteJob(() => DoStuff("a", 10, new string[] {"x", "y", "z"}));
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

In provided case you can achieve at least parts of this using [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) and [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=netcore-3.1):

```
public static int DoStuff(string par1, int par2, string[] arraypar, int JobID)
{
    // JobID is set by JobHandlerManager.ExecuteJob
    return 1;
}
public static void ExternalMethod()
{
    JobHandlerManager.ExecuteJob(() => DoStuff("a", 10, new string[] { "x", "y", "z" },1));
}

public static class JobHandlerManager
{
    public static T ExecuteJob<T>(Expression<Func<T>> MetodoDaEseguire, [CallerMemberName]string caller = "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(caller); // will print "ExternalMethod"
        var mc = MetodoDaEseguire.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", mc.Method.GetParameters().Select(p => p.Name))); // will print "par1, par2, arraypar, JobID"
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", mc.Arguments)); // will print ""a", 10, new [] {"x", "y", "z"}, 1"
        return MetodoDaEseguire.Compile()();    
    }
}
```

And calling `ExternalMethod();` will print:

```
ExternalMethod
par1, par2, arraypar, JobID
"a", 10, new [] {"x", "y", "z"}, 1
```

But beware of performance and closures (i.e. to get actual values passed from local variables, fields, etc. more work will be needed to be done).

To get caller class you can try to look into [`Environment.StackTrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.stacktrace?view=netcore-3.1) or [`CallerFilePathAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute?view=netcore-3.1) for example (depends on your needs).

**UPD**

To replace some of the arguments you can do something like this:

```
var newArgs = mc.Arguments.ToList();
var ardIdToReplace = newArgs.Count - 1; // find somehow index of replaced argument
newArgs[ardIdToReplace] = Expression.Constant(42);
var newLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(Expression.Call(mc.Method, newArgs));
return newLambda.Compile()();
```

Bear in mind this also can be quite error prone cause due to custom handling of expression you loose a lot of compile time safety (user can pass a lot of more then my solution can support).

Comment: In your solution it's not possible: 1) call method with default parameter value. 2) edit JobID value before call the Func Delegate

Comment: @DanieleFrisenna 2) you can manipulate the expression tree, including substituting some of the arguments.

Comment: Can You help me about how can I edit value before call method ?

Comment: I modified my code as you mentioned in the UPD and not work if I call: ExecuteJob passing a method defined inside the caller class (ex: JobHandlerManager.ExecuteJob(() => DoStuff("a", 10, new string[] {"x", "y", "z"}));) but if I a use a static method work perfectly

Comment: @DanieleFrisenna try changing to `Expression.Call(mc.Object, mc.Method, newArgs)`

Comment: I modified metod as you mentioned in the last comment and now all works perfectly. But now I need to know how can I pass Func delegate that have a default value to JobHandlerManager.ExecuteJob

Comment: @DanieleFrisenna I'm afraid it is not possible with expression trees (at least I don't know how) - you need to specify all parameters.

Comment: As you can see in New UPD I have a new problem. Do you know how can solve this

Answer (score 0):

I found by my self a solution form my last problem, including this two method inside ma static class.

```
            private static object GetArgumentValue(Expression element)
            {
                if (element is ConstantExpression)
                {
                    return (element as ConstantExpression).Value;
                }
    
                var l = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Convert(element, element.Type));
                return l.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
            }
    
            private static string[] GetParamArgumentsValue(ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> Arguments)
            {
                List<string> ParamArgumentsValue = new List<string>();
                foreach (var arg in Arguments)
                {
                    ParamArgumentsValue.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetArgumentValue(arg)));
                }
                return ParamArgumentsValue.ToArray();
            }
```

[image]